# Nodejs send request limit Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, request

The code works, when the loop counter is below than 28, but when increase the number to 30 and send more request, it raises the "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000"

Of course this is not the Nodejs limitation, because as I read, "Nodejs can handle 40K request per second".

So, what is my mistake?

```
import request from 'request';

const createFakeReq = (side, index, qty = 1) => {
  const uids = ['633bcf72d4505924dbef9389', '6342477ad7bd5cde3fcd0312'];
  const portfoIds = ['6342f0b9273033fa18e2342b', '63428f1e0bc1349612f97a2d'];
  const quantity = qty;

  const req = {
    portfoId: portfoIds[index],
    uid: uids[index],
    side: side,
    symbol: 'a',
    openPrice: '5020',
    closePrice: '0',
    quantity: quantity,
    openTimetime: '',
    closeTime: '',
    tp: '',
    sl: '',
    isPosition: 'false',
    fill: '0',
    remainder: '',
  };
  return req;
};

const sendReq = async object => {
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/order/make-order',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(object),
  };

  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
  });
};

const deleteAll = async () => {
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/order/drop/0',
    headers: {},
  };
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
  });
};

const asycnReq = async () => {
  await deleteAll();

  for (let i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
    sendReq(createFakeReq('buy', 0));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('sell', 0));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('sell', 0));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('buy', 0));

    sendReq(createFakeReq('sell', 1));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('buy', 1));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('buy', 1));
    sendReq(createFakeReq('sell', 1));
  }
};

export default asycnReq;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnodejs%5D+Error%3A+connect+ECONNREFUSED+127.0.0.1%3A5000

Comment: This is creating 8 requests in a synchronous loop, so ~ 240 requests are created and sent at once. Although a simple node server might be able to respond to "40k requests" a single node client like this won't be able to generate that load, and will need to queue outgoing requests at some point before generating more (it seems about 240 in flight requests, although you may get better throughput at a lower level than that)

Comment: @Matt you mean a normal node server or cloud can handle it? And about queueing your right. It worked, even with 300 requests. Sorry I upvoted you and then accidently downvoted and now it doesn't allow me to upvot again.